# azure active directory add external user via api

Tags: azure, active-directory

How can I add an external user to my Azure AD via the graph api?

I can add an external user (microsoft life account) via the azure portal. But when I try to add a user via the Graph Api it wants a password profile which I think isn't needed.

Can someone point me in a direction?

Answer (score 3):

See this link:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-DotNet

This is a sample MVC Web application that shows how to make RESTful calls to the Graph API to access Azure Active Directory data. It includes use of OWIN libraries to authenticate/authorize using Open ID connect, and a Graph API .Net library.

The sample contains a Create action in the UsersController that creates a user in the Azure AD.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this sample creates a new user to the AD.  What I want is create a new External user. Like in the Management Portal when you add a new user and select the type of user - User with an existing microsoft account.

Comment: I believe this is not possible via the Graph API, but I am not 100% sure. As far as I know (and also according to the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/hh974476.aspx)) the API only provides operations on objects inside the AD of your tenant.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, I do not believe the Graph API supports the ability to add external users. This includes users with MSAs or users from other Azure Active Directory Tenants.

This is a feature request you might raise at: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory

We would love to hear more about your scenario though, as it might drive a stronger push.

Comment: Our intension is that we can authorize users to our web application by adding them as an external user to our directory. This scenario works when we add them via the azure mgmt portal. But we like to do this from our own admin section in the web application.

Comment: I also have come across same kind of scenario. is there any other means to achieve that?